# array of pointers to objects in another class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, constructor

I have to create class like `DataBase` that will contain menu, adding users, editing them, deleting etc.
Users are from class `User`.

It looks like:

```
 class base
 {
    protected int mAccounts=0;
    protected const int mMaxAccs=10;


    osoba[] list = new osoba[mMaxAccs];


    public void menu(){...}
    public void add()
    {
         user user1("Jurand","ze Spychowa",15231512,"1410-10-26","hue@x.com");
         mAccounts++;
    }

    ... useless code there

 }
```

then  there is `User` class

```
class user
    {
        private string mName;
        private string mSurname;
        private int mPesel;
        private DateTime mBDate;
        private string mEmail;

        osoba(string mName2, string mSurname2, string mPesel2, string mBDate2, string mEmail2)
            {
                mName = mName2;
                mSurname = mSurname2;
                mPesel = Convert.ToInt32(mPesel2);
                mBDate = Convert.ToDateTime(mBDate2);
                mEmail = mEmail2;
            }
```

The problem is adding new accounts. I totally don't know how to make it working
So the users will be stored in base class and you will have access to edit and add them etc.

Anyone know how to make it working (Creating objects properly)?

Comment: A good start would be not having the class and its fields (or rather, properties) `private`. You can't access them from the outside if they're not public. Also, the constructor parameters can have the same names, just use `this.mName = mName;` - the `this` refers to the class reference (so you're accessing the fields), and without it, you're getting the parameters, since they have priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding properties to User class:

```
class User
{
    public string mName { get; private set; }
    public string mSurname { get; private set; }
    public int mPesel { get; private set; }
    public DateTime mBDate { get; private set; }
    public string mEmail { get; private set; }

    //constructor for User class
    public User(string mName2, string mSurname2, string mPesel2, string mBDate2, string mEmail2)
    {
            mName = mName2;
            mSurname = mSurname2;
            mPesel = Convert.ToInt32(mPesel2);
            mBDate = Convert.ToDateTime(mBDate2);
            mEmail = mEmail2;
    }
}
```

and modify your add method (also changed object where you store data from array to List):

```
class MyDB
 {

    List<User> list = new List<User>();

    public void add()
    {
         //use constructor to create new object
         User person = new User("Jurand", "ze Spychowa","15231512","1410-10-26","hue@dupa.com");
         //add object to list
         list.Add(person);
    }
 }
```

Its not good idea to mix different languages in code so try avoiding naming objects/methods like "osoba".

You will probably benefit from reading following articles (in Polish):
[C# Constructors](http://4programmers.net/C_sharp/Konstruktory_i_Destruktory)
[C# Properties](http://4programmers.net/C_sharp/W%C5%82a%C5%9Bciwo%C5%9Bci)

Answer (score 0):

I belive that only thing that is missing in your `add()` method is:

```
osoba[mAccounts] = user1;
```

before `mAccounts++` line.

Make fields public only if your `User` class is going to be stupid data object which only store data and contain no methods (maybe except formatting, converting etc.).